# Want to add new tag "canva"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-request

I tried to add the new tag "canva" but received this error:

> The tag [canva] is too similar to [canvas].
> If you think this new tag should be allowed, discuss it on meta.

So here I am to discuss it.

"[Canva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canva)" is a popular design tool that sometimes is even used to create web-sites.

Comment: What kind of programming question could be asked regarding this tool? What would you put in the tag guidance excerpt? ***If*** the tag were to be created, couldn't a less ambiguous form be chosen, like _"canva-visual-suite"_? (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tag-creation-request/info)

Comment: At a quick look, I don't see how the tool would be on-topic for [so]; it looks like it's not a programming tool, but a graphical design tool.

Comment: I propose to modify this question into "What's the best name for this tag: (canva-visual-suite, canva-graphics, canva-design-tool, ...)?".

Comment: If you have examples of existing questions that you believe *are* on topic for Stack Overflow, but would also be suitable for a canva tag, that would make the request much, much more compelling.

Comment: *So here I am to discuss it.* Kind of a one-sided discussion.

Answer (score 12):

The Canva tool you linked to is a visual editing tool, not a programming one, so a [canva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canva) tag itself would be off-topic. However, one *can* write code while creating a Canva *extension*: https://www.canva.dev/docs/extensions/extensions/content-extensions/quick-start/#example

So if you think that second kind of tag is worth creating, it would be appropriate to name it something like [canva-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canva-extension) or similar. It's appropriate when creating tags to make sure they are as specific as possible to avoid tags being misused by those users who don't read tag descriptions. For example, a [canva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canva) tag would surely be misused by thousands of questions over the years by people wanting to ask about the Canvas API or other things related to/called "Canvas".

Note, however, that in order for a tag to exist, at least one question where said tag is appropriate needs to exist already. If you don't already have such a question in mind, stop here and wait until one exists.